# How to change ActionBar Tab textStyle?

Tags: android

By default android actionBar Tab has text-style as CAPITAL. How can I set the text-style to normal camel-case style. Like "Abcd" instead of "ABCD"(Which is the by-default style)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make the tab text lowercase, create a style that inherits `Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText` `Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText` and set `android:textAllCaps` to `false`.

You can apply your own `ActionBar.Tab` text style by using the `android:actionBarTabTextStyle` attribute.

For `AppCompat` compatibility, your style should inherit `Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabText` or `Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText` and the attributes are the same as above, minus the `android` prefix.

For more information, you should read: [Styling the ActionBar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html)

Here's an example with `AppCompat` compatibility:

**values**

```
<style name="Your.Theme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/Your.TabText.Style</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/Your.TabText.Style</item>
</style>

<style name="Your.TabText.Style" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

**values-v14**

```
<style name="Your.TabText.Style" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

**Results**

[image: Example]

Comment: But the problem is it requires API 14(minimum) .. I need something that run in API 9(minimum)...

Comment: @user3565490 I made an edit. Also, in the future you should include details like that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Apply custom theme to your app where you can change actionbar's properties.

```
<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: But the problem is it requires API 14(minimum) .. I need something that run in API 9(minimum)... –