# Xamarin Forms - Android tab text to camel case

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to get my tab text on a Xamarin Forms Android app to camel case. Like this:
[How to change ActionBar Tab textStyle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250105/how-to-change-actionbar-tab-textstyle)

I have tried lots of the examples on Stack overflow but cannot get any to work. Below is my styles.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <resources>

    <style name="Theme.Splash"
        parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
  </style>
  <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
  <style name="MainTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!--If you are using revision 22.1 please use just windowNoTitle. Without android:-->
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette -->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#96BCE3</item>
    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>

    <item name="android:colorPressedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
    <item name="android:colorLongPressedHighlight">@color/ListViewHighlighted</item>
    <item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
    <item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@color/ListViewSelected</item>

    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item> <!-- This works for buttons not tab page text -->"

  </style>

  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#96BCE3</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

Thanks
Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please open `Tabbar.xml` file like following path

[image]

Then add `app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"` like following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

    app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"

    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

Comment: If this answer is helpful, please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) it will help others who have similar issue

Comment: Brilliant, thanks very much. I had almost given up trying.