# How can I customize the appearance of top tabs (ShellSection) in Xamarin Shell?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, custom-renderer, xamarin.forms.shell

I’ve done a lot of research:

- [How to change ActionBar Tab textStyle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250105/how-to-change-actionbar-tab-textstyle)
- [TabLayout Tab Title text in Lower Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33015652/tablayout-tab-title-text-in-lower-case)
- https://github.com/Andy671/Dachshund-Tab-Layout/issues/2
- https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2551

However, I couldn’t find how to implement what I have in mind correctly.

My application uses Xamarin Shell with a flyout menu, and some of the pages present a top tab bar. To give you an example, my application looks like this:

[image]

[Xamarin Shell provides a simple way to create these multi-tabs pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs#bottom-and-top-tabs). Now, I want to customize these tabs and change the font, the color of the selection indicator, and so on. In the beginning, I thought I could just create a specific style in the `styles.xml` file of my Android project and reference it in `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout`. To give you an example, I did something like this in the `Tabbar.xml` file inside the Android project of my Xamarin solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
   app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
   style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
   app:tabGravity="fill"
   app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

and this inside the `styles.xml` file always inside the Android project of the solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">3dp</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

However, nothing happened, and the style wasn’t applied. I thought it was a misunderstanding of how to really implement what I had in mind, and I thought that maybe the "sub" top tab bar wasn’t considered a true `TabLayout`, since it was just a product of `ShellSection`. In the end, I found that maybe what I needed was a [custom renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/customrenderers#create-a-custom-renderer-class). I’m on my way to implement it, but I’m stuck on this issue: I don’t understand how to set the appearance of the `ShellSection`. My current code for the custom renderer is this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AppShell), typeof(CustomShellRenderer))]
namespace A {
    internal class CustomShellRenderer : ShellRenderer {
        public CustomShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

        protected override IShellSectionRenderer CreateShellSectionRenderer(ShellSection shellSection) {
            return new CustomShellSectionAppearance(this);
        }
    }

    class CustomShellSectionAppearance : ShellSectionRenderer {
        public Fragment Fragment { get; }
        public event EventHandler AnimationFinished;
        public void Dispose() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public ShellSection ShellSection { get; set; }

        public CustomShellSectionAppearance(IShellContext shellContext) : base(shellContext) { }

        // I thought I need to make my customization here, but it was only a guess:
        // I found nobody talking about customizing a ShellSection on the Web
        protected override void SetAppearance(ShellAppearance appearance) {
            base.SetAppearance(appearance);
            appearance.TabBarDisabledColor = Color.Aqua; // ERROR: appearance has only "get" properties
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something in the process of customizing the appearance of the top tab bar of my Xamarin application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with the following Shell custom renderer.

- For colors: the parameters names of `SetColors(TabLayout tabLayout, Color foreground, Color background, Color title, Color unselected)` method are self-explanatory.
- If Color type is not precede by a namespace in below code then it is from XF, because of `using Color = Xamarin.Forms.Color;`
- For Font you need to create a custom view and define whatever attributes you want.
- You may modify an attribute, change style or do any logic when selection changed using `TabSelected` and `TabUnSelected` events, in my demo I am applying bold on text and make it bigger when tab is selected and reverting back when tab is unselected, you may implement a nice animation there also.

```
public class MyShellRenderer : ShellRenderer
{
    public MyShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override IShellTabLayoutAppearanceTracker CreateTabLayoutAppearanceTracker(ShellSection shellSection)
        => new MyTabLayoutAppearanceTracker(this);
}


public class MyTabLayoutAppearanceTracker : ShellTabLayoutAppearanceTracker
{
    public MyTabLayoutAppearanceTracker(IShellContext shellContext) : base(shellContext)
    {
    }

    public override void SetAppearance(TabLayout tabLayout, ShellAppearance appearance)
    {
        base.SetAppearance(tabLayout, appearance);
        tabLayout.TabSelected += TabLayout_TabSelected;
        tabLayout.TabUnselected += TabLayout_TabUnselected;

        for (var i = 0; i < tabLayout.TabCount; i++)
        {
            TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.GetTabAt(i);
            if (tab.CustomView == null)
            {
                TextView textview = new TextView(Android.App.Application.Context)
                {
                    Text = tabLayout.GetTabAt(i).Text,
                    TextSize = 20,
                    Typeface = Typeface.DefaultBold
                };
                textview.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
                tab.SetCustomView(textview);
            }
        }
        base.SetColors(tabLayout, Color.Red, Color.Yellow, Color.Black, Color.Gray);
    }
        private void TabLayout_TabUnselected(object sender, TabLayout.TabUnselectedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Tab?.CustomView is TextView textView)
            {
                textView.Typeface = Typeface.Default;
                textView.TextSize = 15;
            }
        }

        private void TabLayout_TabSelected(object sender, TabLayout.TabSelectedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Tab?.CustomView is TextView textView)
            {
                textView.Typeface = Typeface.DefaultBold;
                textView.TextSize = 20;
            }
        }
}
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

An easier solution without custom renderer?

Take a look at [**TabView**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/tabview) from `xamarin-communitytoolkit` package.

Comment: This may affect the bottom Tabs too, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the colour of the selected tab without the hassle of custom renderers you can do this by editing the Shell Tab's ShellUnselectedColor, ShellTitleColor, and ShellForegroundColor:

```
  <Style x:Key="BaseStyle"
                   TargetType="Element">
                <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor"
                        Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor"
                        Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor"
                        Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor"
                        Value="#B4FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor"
                        Value="#95FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor"
                        Value="{StaticResource Primary}" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor"
                        Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor"
                        Value="#95FFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor"
                        Value="White" />
            </Style>
```

Comment: I believe this will affect the bottom Tabs and the navigation bar as well. The @op want to change the font also.